# Custom CSS overrides Salesforce CSS

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm not sure how to work around Salesforce's styling by namespacing custom CSS files and applying that namespace to styled section of the Visualforce page.

As you can see my salesforce page is messed-up

[image]
Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page >
    <style>

        @font-face {
        font-family: SourceSansPro;
        src: url(SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
        }

        .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
        }

        a {
        color: #0087C3;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
        position: relative;
        width: 21cm;  
        height: 29.7cm; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        color: #555555;
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
        font-size: 14px; 
        font-family: SourceSansPro;
        }

        header {
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        }

        #logo {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 8px;
        }

        #logo img {
        height: 70px;
        }

        #company {
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
        }


        #details {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        #client {
        padding-left: 6px;
        border-left: 6px solid #0087C3;
        float: left;
        }

        #client .to {
        color: #777777;
        }

        h2.name {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        }

        #invoice {
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
        }

        #invoice h1 {
        color: #0087C3;
        font-size: 2.4em;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0  0 10px 0;
        }

        #invoice .date {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        color: #777777;
        }

        table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        table th,
        table td {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #EEEEEE;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        }

        table th {
        white-space: nowrap;        
        font-weight: normal;
        }

        table td {
        text-align: right;
        }

        table td h3{
        color: #57B223;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
        }

        table .no {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        background: #57B223;
        }

        table .desc {
        text-align: left;
        }

        table .unit {
        background: #DDDDDD;
        }

        table .qty {
        }

        table .total {
        background: #57B223;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        table td.unit,
        table td.qty,
        table td.total {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        table tbody tr:last-child td {
        border: none;
        }

        table tfoot td {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        white-space: nowrap; 
        border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
        }

        table tfoot tr:first-child td {
        border-top: none; 
        }

        table tfoot tr:last-child td {
        color: #57B223;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        border-top: 1px solid #57B223; 

        }

        table tfoot tr td:first-child {
        border: none;
        }

        #thanks{
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        #notices{
        padding-left: 6px;
        border-left: 6px solid #0087C3;  
        }

        #notices .notice {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        footer {
        color: #777777;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        padding: 8px 0;
        text-align: center;
        }


    </style>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>

            <title>Example 2</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
        </head>
        <body class="bs">
            <header class="clearfix">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png"/>
                </div>
                <div id="company">
                    <h2 class="name">Company Name</h2>
                    <div>455 Foggy Heights, AZ 85004, US</div>
                    <div>(602) 519-0450</div>
                    <div><a href="mailto:company@example.com">company@example.com</a></div>
                </div>

            </header>
            <main>
                <div id="details" class="clearfix">
                    <div id="client">
                        <div class="to">INVOICE TO:</div>
                        <h2 class="name">John Doe</h2>
                        <div class="address">796 Silver Harbour, TX 79273, US</div>
                        <div class="email"><a href="mailto:john@example.com">john@example.com</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="invoice">
                        <h1>INVOICE 3-2-1</h1>
                        <div class="date">Date of Invoice: 01/06/2014</div>
                        <div class="date">Due Date: 30/06/2014</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="no">#</th>
                            <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
                            <th class="unit">UNIT PRICE</th>
                            <th class="qty">QUANTITY</th>
                            <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no">01</td>
                            <td class="desc"><h3>Website Design</h3>Creating a recognizable design solution based on the company's existing visual identity</td>
                            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
                            <td class="qty">30</td>
                            <td class="total">$1,200.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no">02</td>
                            <td class="desc"><h3>Website Development</h3>Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
                            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
                            <td class="qty">80</td>
                            <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="no">03</td>
                            <td class="desc"><h3>Search Engines Optimization</h3>Optimize the site for search engines (SEO)</td>
                            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
                            <td class="qty">20</td>
                            <td class="total">$800.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
                            <td>$5,200.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td colspan="2">TAX 25%</td>
                            <td>$1,300.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
                            <td>$6,500.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <div id="thanks">Thank you!</div>
                <div id="notices">
                    <div>NOTICE:</div>
                    <div class="notice">A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer>
                Invoice was created on a computer and is valid without the signature and seal.
            </footer>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You should set `applyHtmlTag="false"` when adding your own. It doesn't relate to the issue at hand but just a heads up.

Comment: thanks and also you need to add `showHeader="false"` along with `applyHtmlTag="false"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use namespace in css. You can simply do this

```
<html lang="en" class="nameCustom">
```

Now in your css append this

```
.nameCustom .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
        }

       .nameCustom  a {
        color: #0087C3;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: `<html lang="en" class="nameCustom">` where do you defined that line?

Comment: @NickKahn in your closing style tag the next line.

Comment: ah ha i see what you mean